# Isometric embedding of Schwarzchild metric in $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, topology

I am reading through this article https://arxiv.org/abs/1010.4256  about the special case of the positive mass theorem in general relativity. I do not understand the section below:

[image]

In particular what does it mean to isometrically embed an $n$-dimensional Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ in a higher dimensional space, and where does the embedding given for the  $n=3$ Schwarzschild metric come from? I assume we are referring to the standard definition of isometric embeddings using pullbacks of covariant tensor fields.

I assume the author refers to the map between Riemannian manifolds $f: \mathbb{R}^3-B_{2m}\to\mathbb{R}^4$ given by $f(x,y,z)=(x,y,z,\sqrt{8m(r-2m)})$. I have tried to check if the Schwarzchild metric on $\mathbb{R}^3$ is the pullback of the flat metric on $\mathbb{R}^{4}$, however this doesn't appear to be true...

Comment: An isometric embedding is a injective smooth map that maintains the metric, i.e. an invertible map $\phi: M\to N$ with $v,w\in T_pM$ then $\phi_* : TM\to TN$ has the property that $g_N(\phi_* v,\phi_*w)=g_M(v,w)$. This means that $\phi^* g_N=g_M$.

Comment: @J.V.Gaiter I am aware of the definition. What is not clear here is what map the author is using (is it $f$? if so, computing the pullback of the flat metric on R^4 by f does not appear to give the schwarzchild metric on R^3). I have checked my computations...