# Isometric embedding of embedding of Schwarzchild metric

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, topology

I am reading through this article https://arxiv.org/abs/1010.4256  about the special case of the positive mass theorem in general relativity. I do not understand the section below:

[image]

In particular what does it mean to isometrically embed an $n$-dimensional Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ in a higher dimensional space, and where does the embedding given for the  $n=3$ Schwarzschild metric come from? I assume we are referring to the standard definition of isometric embeddings using pullbacks of covariant tensor fields.

I assume the author refers to the map between Riemannian manifolds $f: \mathbb{R}^3-B_{2m}\to\mathbb{R}^4$ given by $f(x,y,z)=(x,y,z,\sqrt{8m(r-2m)})$. I have tried to check if the Schwarzchild metric on $\mathbb{R}^3$ is the pullback of the flat metric on $\mathbb{R}^{4}$, however this doesn't appear to be true...

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/610964/2451

Comment: Hi Joshua Benabou. Please don't repost a question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.